# Check constructor element with analyzer in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a library in Flutter to generate code for the annotated elements. I need to check the parameter in the constructor of class is required using analyzer.

Example of widget with annotation:

```dart
@myAnnotation
class WidgetText extends StatelessWidget {
  WidgetText({
    @required this.text,
    this.subtitle,
  });

  final String text;
  final String subtitle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(text),
        if (subtitle != null) Text(subtitle),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Example of my visitor:

```dart
class MyAnnotationVisitor extends SimpleElementVisitor<void> {
  @override
  void visitFieldElement(FieldElement element) {
    print('${element.name} is required? ${element.hasRequired}');
  }
}
```

This visitor above output this for `WidgetText`

```sh
text is required? false
subtitle is required? false
```

The visitor can verify if the field is required only when an annotation is marked on the field this way below. But is repetitive and I would like to check in the constructor.

```dart
@myAnnotation
class WidgetText extends StatelessWidget {
  WidgetText({
    @required this.text,
    this.subtitle,
  });

  @required
  final String text;
  final String subtitle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(text),
        if (subtitle != null) Text(subtitle),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible analyzing `ParameterElement`. Has a get called `hasRequired`.